# Best approach for returning result from a method

Tags: c++

I have to make a function/method in C++ for implementing merge sort that takes two vectors as input and stores the result in another vector. Which is the best approach for such a function:

1. Return a pointer to the result vector.
2. Return the result vector.
3. Include a third vector in the function's argument list to place the result in.

Which of these approach will be recommended.

Comment: Chances are NRVO is going to deal with it, and even if it didn't move semantics would. Return by value.

Comment: Option 1 is not viable if the 'result' vector is a local variable. Then the local variable will be destroyed when the function is exited.

Comment: It heavily depends on your context. But if there's nothing in your code that explicitly demands 1st or 3rd option i would definitely stick to the 2nd

Comment: Edited the question to add some context.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal; what if that loacal variable is actually a pointer?

Comment: 3 primary oppinion based flags? Seriously? Is primary opinion based ask how modern compilers work? Thats anoying.

Comment: "Primarily opinion-based"? Seriously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, this is the clearest way to do that:

```
typedef std::vector<int> int_vector;

int_vector get_vector() {
    int_vector vect;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vect), 100, std::random);
    return vect;
}

int main() {
    int_vector vect = get_vector();
    // do smth
}
```

The vect variable from get_vector() function should be optimized out. Compiler transforms get_vector method so that vect variable from main is passed as a pointer to it, so no coping is needed. This is called NRVO. However, this is not guaranteed by the standard, and can not be supported in the older ones. If you want a guaranteed way to do it without coping, pass a refernece:

```
typedef std::vector<int> int_vector;

int_vector get_vector(int_vector& vect) {
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vect), 100, std::random);
    return vect;
}

int main() {
    int_vector vect;
    get_vector(vect);
    // do smth
}
```

But, IMHO, it is a compiler's job to do it.

Update: if your compiler supports c++11, even if it would not be able to do nrvo optimization, vector would be moved in first example, not copied.

Comment: So this means that I can use 'approach 1' and let compiler  use NRVO to optimize it (provided I'm using a modern compiler (Visual C++ 2012)).

Comment: See my update about c++11. Unfortunately, I don't have much expirience with msvs compiler, but I've seen some articles about nrvo in visual 2010.

Comment: Pardon my English, does that (the updates part of post) mean that C++11 will make vectors pass by reference irrespective of NRVO? Will this depend on the fact that whether the vectors is being modified in the function?

Comment: с++11 will prevent the vector deep copy (see [ravlue references](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html)). I mean that even in the worst possible case, return by value will be fast (memory will be allocated only once) even if nrvo is not used. So, if you can use c++11, prefer to return by value. Even without it you can do it, but you have to check if nrvo is used.

Answer (score -1):

You can also create a reference to avoid unnecessary copying:

```
    typedef vector<int> MyVector;

    MyVector addVectors(const MyVector& vec1, const MyVector& vec2)
    {
        MyVector result;
        if ( vec1.size() == vec2.size() )
            for (size_t i = 0; i < vec1.size(); i++)
                result.push_back(vec1[i]+vec2[i]);
        return result;
    }

    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        MyVector v1 = {1,2,3,4};
        MyVector v2 = {5,6,7,8};
        const MyVector& result = addVectors(v1,v2);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "*You can also create a reference to avoid unnecessary copying*" No, no , no. Value semantics are a key concept of moder optimizing compilers. Returning by value (and getting) is perfectly reasonable, there are many copy ellision optimizations ( (N)RVO ) which any decent compiler can do. References break many optimization opportunities becuse most of the optimizations techniques are based on value semantics. The compiler canmnot easily inline a method with reference parameters, for example (Because of the posible side effect and/or aliasing). So **Always return by value and get by value**.

Comment: Manu please give some links on reading about "get by value optimizations" ?

Comment: As I said, optimizers rely on value semantics. The problem in C++ is that by value means *copying* by default. **But thats not the case always**. You should think as "by value return/pass" instead of "returning by copy or passing by copy". The best guideline is: Just pass/return by value and let the compiler decide how to perform it (Moving, copying, or just doing nothing).

Comment: @vjdy See [this article](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) for example